# Is there a way to reshape a Pandas Series into bins based on time intervals and select one of them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

So I have a timeseries stored on a Pandas Series:

```py
data = pd.Series(data=[0,1,3,5], index=pd.to_timedelta([0, 15, 30, 45], unit='min'))
```

I wanted to group those data into 30 minute intervals, and then select all the data of the second interval. By looking at the docs, it can find the sum, mean or do other things with the values, but I can't find a way to return all the data as they are as a Pandas Series.

So something like this, but obviously this syntax is wrong:

```py
new_data.resample('30min').iloc[1]
```

So, if I have the Series like this:

```
0 days 00:00:00    0
0 days 00:15:00    1
0 days 00:30:00    3
0 days 00:45:00    5
```

I'd like to get:

```
0 days 00:30:00    3
0 days 00:45:00    5
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general way of achieving that (can be useful if you can not guarantee that you array will start at xx:00:xx)

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

data = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=pd.to_timedelta(['0:30:00', '1:15:00', '2:45:00']))

mask = np.floor(data.index.seconds / (30 * 60)) % 2 == 1

print(data[mask])
```